# Cannot print from network printer while on terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, printing

I have two (local) network printers - HP PSC 750xi & Samsung ML-1710. While connected to the remote Terminal Server I am able to print on the HP. However, when I try to print on the Samsung, the printer activates as if it's going to print and then does nothing. Anyone know what I need to do in order to print on the Samsung? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The terminal server does have the appropriate drivers for both printers -- in the case of the Samsung it is the "Samsung Unified Print Driver."

When I print, the printer queue takes the target document and moments later removes it as if it was successfully printed. When I check the event viewer (of the TS) there is a notice that states:

> "Document owned by Dan was printed on
>   Samsung Universal Print  Driver in
>   session 1 via port TS001."

But unfortunately, the printer *does not* actually print any document.

Comment: Does that driver match the one installed on the client? If not, I recommend installing the same driver as the client has, as those generic drivers are more trouble than they're worth and are best avoided.

Comment: Yes, the drivers on the TS and the client are the same. Since the Samsung is a network printer, through "Control Panel" > "Printers & Faxes" I added the Samsung print to the TS. That's how I know both the TS & client have the same drivers. Moreover, the "Samsung Unified Driver" is what is automatically loaded when you "add" the printer. As a side note, since I "added" the printer to the TS, I'm able to print from the TS on the Samsung via the network rather than through client redirection. Do you have any other suggestions/ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the correct drivers are installed on the Terminal Services Server.

Comment: +1 This is usually the issue

Comment: The correct drivers are installed on the TS. I've edited my original post with more information -- please see above.

Answer (score 0):

If your Samsung installed as network printer on client (local printer with TCP/IP or other network port assigned for printing) - try to implement changes in Windows client registry to force ALL client ports redirect to terminal session as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302361)